# remove Odata.metadata in asp.net web api OdataController

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

How to remove in asp.net odata.metadata attribute in an odatacontroller.

I have the following code:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyViewModels(ODataQueryOptions<CompanyViewModel> queryOptions)
    {
        IQueryable<CompanyViewModel> result = companiesService.GetCompanies();

        return Ok<IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>>(result);          
    }
```

that returns this.

```
 "odata.metadata": "http://localhost:63447/odata/$metadata#CompanyViewModels",
    "value":[
    {
    "Id": 1,
    "CompanyName": "Company1"
    },
    {
    "Id": 2,
    "CompanyName": "Company2"
    }
    ]
```

How can i remove the "odata.metadata" portion.

I tried to remove the 'MetadataRoutingConvention' from the conventions but it has no effect.Just makes the link not accesible.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same problem

Comment: @Ehsan See my comment below

Answer (score 4):

Add option `$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none`when querying can make odata.metadata (actually should be odata.context according to odata spec) does not show in the payload.
For example:
http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=none

MetadataRoutingConvention is specifically used to generate the response of `~/$metadata`. That's why removing it would make your http://localhost:63447/odata/$metadata inaccesible.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had $format=json;odata.metadata=none, but I changed it to $format=application/json;odata.metadata=none and it worked like a charm.